# TinyMCE shows builder font change tags

Tags: system-font

After integration, I used to create a template and save the HTML source code. After I view that HTML code it shows the below as in the attached screenshot.

[image]

Inside that editor shows like the below-attached screenshot:

[image]

Here is my code

```
var tinyconfig = {
                  skin: 'oxide-dark',
                  inline: true,
                  menubar: false,
                  force_br_newlines : false,
                  force_p_newlines : false,
                  forced_root_block : '',
                  inline_boundaries: false,
                  relative_urls: false,
                  convert_urls: false,
                  remove_script_host : false,
                  valid_elements : '*[*],meta[*]',
                  valid_children: '+h1[div],+h2[div],+h3[div],+h4[div],+h5[div],+h6[div],+a[div]',
                  plugins: 'image link textcolor lists autolink',
                  //toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic underline | fontselect fontsizeselect | forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignfull | numlist bullist outdent indent',
                  // toolbar: [
                      // 'undo redo | bold italic underline | fontselect fontsizeselect | link | menuDateButton',
                      // 'forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignfull | numlist bullist outdent indent'
                  // ],
                  toolbar:false,
                  external_filemanager_path:'{{ url('/') }}'.replace('/index.php','')+"/filemanager2/",
                  filemanager_title:"Responsive Filemanager" ,
                  external_plugins: { "filemanager" : '{{ url('/') }}'.replace('/index.php','')+"/filemanager2/plugin.min.js"},
                  setup: function (editor) {
                  
                      /* Menu button that has a simple "insert date" menu item, and a submenu containing other formats. */
                      /* Clicking the first menu item or one of the submenu items inserts the date in the selected format. */
                      editor.ui.registry.addMenuButton('menuDateButton', {
                        text: getI18n('editor.insert_tag'),
                        fetch: function (callback) {
                          var items = [];

                          thisEditor.tags.forEach(function(tag) {
                              if ( tag.type == 'label') {
                                  items.push({
                                      type: 'menuitem',
                                      text: tag.tag.replace("{", "").replace("}", ""),
                                      onAction: function (_) {
                                          if (tag.text) {
                                              editor.insertContent(tag.text);
                                          } else {
                                              editor.insertContent(tag.tag);
                                          }                                            
                                      }
                                  });
                              }
                          });
                          
                          callback(items);
                        }
                      });
                  }
              };
```

Comment: Hi, what's your code?

Comment: hi i added my code